# More than one pickereditor on the same dataform?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, telerik

I am relatively new to Xamarin and the Telerik UI controls for Xamarin.Forms.

I am trying to have two pickereditors on two different model properties on the same dataform but i cant seem to get both data sources to work. I can get one or the other to work but not both. Do i need a separate PropertyDataSourceProvider for each data source?

I have the following:
**LoanDetailsPAge.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:input="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms. and if so how do i achieve thatInput;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.Input"
             x:Class="ccnz.mobile.Pages.LoanApplication.LoanDetailsPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Loan Details"/>
                <input:RadDataForm x:Name="loanDetailsDataForm" Source="{Binding LoanDetail}">
                </input:RadDataForm>
                <Button Text="Previous" Clicked="PreviousButtonClicked" />
                <Button Text="Next" Clicked="NextButtonClicked" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**and code behind LoanDetailsPage.xaml.cs**

```
    public LoanDetailsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        loanDetailsDataForm.PropertyDataSourceProvider = new LoanReasonPropertyDataSourceProvider();
        //loanDetailsDataForm.PropertyDataSourceProvider = new LoanAmountPropertyDataSourceProvider();
        loanDetailsDataForm.ValidationMode = ValidationMode.OnLostFocus;
        loanDetailsDataForm.CommitMode = CommitMode.Manual;
        loanDetailsDataForm.FormValidationCompleted += ValidateAndGoToNextPage;

        loanDetailsDataForm.RegisterEditor(nameof(LoanDetails.LoanReason), EditorType.PickerEditor);
        loanDetailsDataForm.RegisterEditor(nameof(LoanDetails.LoanAmount), EditorType.PickerEditor);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have since worked out how to do it using the example in the Telerik SDKBrowser example i.e. passing in a key to dictate which property i want passed back. Refer to the SourceItem.cs file in the SDKBrowser solution to see how it is done.